# Copying a file in specific folders using Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I have two PDFs -  `.COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 1 to 10.pdf` and `.COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 11 to 20.pdf` kept in the directory `D:\Dropbox\Sample C# Notes`

The folder `Sample C# Notes` also has some subfolders like `0001`, `0002`, `0003` and so on till `0300`.

I am writing the following command (given by SO user lotpings) in a batch file to copy the pdf from `Sample C# Notes` to all the subfolders inside it (0001, 0002, 0003...)

```
for /D %%x in ("D:\Dropbox\Sample C# Notes\*") DO (
  COPY "D:\Dropbox\Sample C# Notes\.COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 1 to 10.pdf" "%%x\"
)
```

How do I modify this code so that I can copy :

`.COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 1 to 10.pdf` into folders `0001` to `0100`

and

`.COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 11 to 20.pdf` into folders `0101` to `0300`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please:

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\Dropbox\Sample C# Notes\"
for /f %%x in ('dir /b /ad 0*') do (
    if %%x leq 0100 (
        COPY ".COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 1 to 10.pdf" "%%x\"
    ) else (
        COPY ".COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 11 to 20.pdf" "%%x\"
    )
)
popd
@echo on
```

To make life easier, I didn't use full dir path, instead I changed working path first, and copy files.
Also since you said there are only `0001` to `0030` these subfolders, so I didn't check `0101` to `0300`, just put them in the `else` block.
You can improve it based on these.

`for /f` used another command `dir`'s output.